# Are edits rewarded with reputation points beyond the 1k mark?

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits

I was wondering if a user, once they accumulate 1000 reputation points, is still rewarded 2 reputation points per question or answer edited.

I'm a bit confused about that as I have already edited two texts since I reached the 1000 reputation mark, for which, apparently, I have not been given any more reputation points.

Any explanation for this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Once a user reaches 1000 on the beta French SE site, they no longer receive +2 rep for editing posts.

Suggested edits created by users under 1000 rep are awarded +2 rep if accepted because they have **now made a contribution** that is considered useful by 2 users with a high level of reputation.

Editing posts (after 1000 rep) is almost considered to be a duty.  The SE model works on the theory of community moderation.

From the [privilege section on editing posts](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **What is edit questions and answers?**
>
> We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've
>   generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the
>   system without it going through the peer review system. Not just your
>   posts—anyone's posts!
>
> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!

Comment: Then I am bound by my duty to continue it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @indoxica This is solely how I interpret it.  Other users may have other things to say about it.  They may not see it as a duty that you have to continue.  It depends on how much you want to contribute to the site really.